# pandas - how to calculate dot product of two columns, each containing arrays of equal length?

Tags: python, pandas

assume you have a pandas dataframe as follows:

```
x = pd.DataFrame(data={
        'x1': [np.array([1,1,1]), np.array([1,2,6])],
        'x2': [np.array([2,3,2]), np.array([3,4,7])] })
```

I'm looking to add a new column to this dataframe, which should contain the dot product of `x1` and `x2`, i.e. my output table should look like:

```
x1      | x2      | result
[1,1,1] | [1,2,6] | 9 (dot product of [1,1,1] and [1,2,6])
[2,3,2] | [3,4,7] | 32 (dot product of [2,3,2] and [3,4,7])
```

How can I do this?

I've tried

```
x.x1.dot(x.x2)
```

however that returns an array `[5,11,44]`, i.e. looks to calculate the dot product in the "wrong" direction.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can using for loop here

```
x['result']=[np.dot(x,y) for x, y  in zip(x.x1,x.x2)]
```

Answer (score 1):

you'd need to access which row to dot: `x.x1[0].dot(x.x1[1])= 9`

When you access the x.x1, you get a pandas series with two rows.

The response @Wen-Ben response shows you how to get the 'results' column in one line.

Answer (score 0):

The same could be done without using dot().

```
x['product'] =df.apply(lambda k: sum(k['x1']*(k['x2'])), axis = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be more easily done by overloading the dot operator on your array, and by "dot" I mean ".".

Thus the correct statement becomes

```
product = x.x1.x.x2;
```

(Note: be sure to have ellipses turned off in your editor for more complex calculations.)